# 404 Error - With Category Base in URL (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I have having really weird problem with Wordpress, I have made some categories like Automotive, CAD etc and I want to keep "topic" as my base url to category URL is something like "www.mywebsite.com/topic/automotive" but When I click on "view" for category, it returns 404 error but If i remove topic from URL to make url look like "www.mywebsite.com/automotive" then category page shows.

I am not able to understand this problem, what could be it and how to resolve it? I tried deactivating all plugins, changed category base from topic to category in permalinks but same issue, url won't show with base it will only show without any base which i don't want.

====== EDIT ======

I JUST NOTICED, IT IS THEME PROBLEM, WHEN I CHANGE THEME, IT WORKS PERFECTLY, SO NOW I HAVE TO FIND OUT THE PART WHERE THE ISSUE IS LYING.

Please help
Regards
Manoj Soni

Comment: have you set your permalink settings ?

Comment: Yes Permalinks set

Comment: may be that theme has some register_taxonomy function which registers non-hierarchic tag called "topic". Have you tried any other string instead of topic? f.e. "topic222". What happens if to set different URL?